# Different price between PDP and cart

Tags: magento2.2, discount, bundle, rounding

A client uses bundle products with discounts, which are set as a percentage of the original price.

The discounted price is rounded to two decimals on the PDP and used in the total price calculation (price * qty)

Because of the percentages the actual price of the product has 4 decimals, which is stored in the quote items.

The problem is that the cart will show a different price that previously calculated because of the rounding before / after applying the qty

Is it possible to force the same calculation for quote items, for example by prerounding the product price ?

Comment: Hi @ElSchaap did u get any solution on this?